# How to create a playlist in Quicktime Player for many files in separate subfolders?

Tags: quicktime, playlist

I have a folder of .mov files that are all part of a video tutorial session. The directory looks like:

```
Tuts/
  Tut1/
    Chapter1/
      1-1.mov
      1-2.mov
      1-3.mov
    Chapter2/
      2-1.mov
      2-2.mov
   Tut2/
     ...
```

While trying to watch this series I have to go back to Finder and open the next .mov file in order to get start the next video. I've been looking around Google and can't seem to find a way to make Quicktime Player just play the videos in order.

Is there any way to import this folder into Quicktime Player and just play them all in order without having to close Quicktime Player, go back to Finder, find the next video, open that video with Quicktime Player?

Comment: I compiled a simple movie player that uses the Quicktime Framework which will play a selection of files in the order you choose; Quicktime Player itself cannot — I'll post it if you're interested.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Can't you just keep a Finder window open next to your Quicktime Player and double click each movie when needed? There is no need to close the Player after every movie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create your own movie player using the QuickTime Framework it's possible to add whatever functionality you want. QuickTime Player itself does not appear to offer playlist capability on Mac OS X. Here's a few screen captures of my movie player using a playlist:

[image: QuickTime w/Playlist]

[image: QuickTime Custom Player]

Comment: Nice... I didn't even know this was possible.

Comment: The app will allow you to save your playlist too. You can download it here: http://goo.gl/uSIIR

Comment: Thanks for sharing.This app will prove to be very useful, especially when viewing lessons from tutorial sites.

Comment: Any verified apps out there that do this?

Comment: @errant.info: Are you meaning verified by an Apple Developer certificate? I suppose that I could sign this one for you if it's more reassuring.

Answer (score 8):

Quicktime Player (X or version 7) doesn't support playlists to my knowledge. You could add the files to a playlist in iTunes, or download [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). I'd highly recommend VLC, it's free, it can tackle pretty much any format you can throw at it (including .mov), and you can just drag and drop files to a playlist to queue them up very simply.

Comment: Interesting.  It's 2016 and I still go to VLC for this.  Just drop in a folder and the sequence starts playing.  Wish there was something more polished but VLC still rocks.

Comment: VLC doesn't honour drag and drop sequence, it always name sorts the playlist.  This doesn't work for me when I want to create a 1000 video playlist from 4 different media sources without renaming the files to have a date prefix using the EXIF data.

Answer (score 2):

Try Graphic Converter. It's good for lots of other things but you can use its slideshow features to play, for example, all the movies in a particular folder. Other than making sure the movies you want are in the folder, you don't have to actually make any kind of playlist. If you have .jpgs in the same folder, it will include them too, as part of your slideshow.

It's shareware, and well worth the US$35 for all the other stuff it does too.

But you can use it for free for a month or so, uncrippled, to see everything it can do.

I don't have the website handy but if you do a search, you'll find it easily enough. LemkeSoft, I believe, is the developer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not for quicktime specifically, but you should check out IINA, it's basically QuickTime ... but 100x better, with playlists and more ... and it's open source and free :)

https://lhc70000.github.io/iina/

Comment: Iina seems to suffer from the same problem as VLC - it doesn't honour drag and drop sequence, it name sorts the playlist. This doesn't work for me when I want to create a 1000 video playlist from 4 different media sources without renaming the files to have a date prefix using the EXIF data.